# Excel VBA IE Get Element's Coordinates For Mouse Click

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Is there a way to get an IE element's mouse coordinates then command a mouse move to that coordinates on the screen to click it? I tried searching for `element.getAttribute` but so far couldn't find what I need.

I simply need the mouse to move/point to an object and click it. I'm needing to do it this way without using `element.click`

Comment: How are you planning on sending a WM_LBUTTONDOWN message?

Comment: @Jeeped I'm sorry I don't know what that is? :s Is that still VBA?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `element.click` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Our company website have scripts/triggers on most of the controls/elements and simply doing an element.click is failing because of the missing steps. I'm just with a smaller branch of the company and which is why I am creating a VBA macro to make my tasks easier. I already know how to do it in Autoit+Excel but would love to have an Excel-only version